# How do I await end result of async chain from elsewhere in my code?

Tags: dart, async-await, flutter

Flutter newbie here. I'm trying to parse some json in dart and am getting confused with the async nature of reading the underlying file.

How do I wait until the *json* has finished parsing and not just the underlying file? My confusion is that reading the file is asynchronous, but parsing the json is synchronous. Now I know that you can use await to wait for the Future to complete that's returned by loadString when reading the file. But how do I then "await" the completion of parsing the json?

jsonDecode does not accept a Future as its arguments and it runs synchronously so I can't wrap it's results into a Future(or can I?). If I could somehow get a Future< Map> _string2Item; as a result of the json parsing operation then that would solve my problem I think since I could simply: await _string2Item before doing anything.

```
class ItemsRepository
{
 Map<String, Item> _string2Item;

  //This does not work unfortunately. However, I don't want to return an instance that hasn't finished parsing the json
  ItemsRepository() async
  {
    await init();
  }

  Future<String> _loadFile() async {
    return await rootBundle.loadString('assets/data/item_int2string.json');
  }

  Future<void> init() async
  {
    var _fileContents = _loadFile();
    _string2Item = jsonDecode(await _fileContents);
  }

  Item getItem(String id)
  {
    return _string2Item[id];
  }
}

//... somewhere else in my code
ItemRepository ir = ItemRepository();
ir.getItem("42"); //this crashes because _string2Item hasn't finished parsing yet.
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
ItemRepository ir = ItemRepository();
await ir.init();
ir.getItem('42');
```

Your class can be written more succinctly as:

```
class ItemsRepository {
  Map<String, Item> _string2Item;

  Future<void> init() async {
    _string2Item = jsonDecode(
        await rootBundle.loadString('assets/data/item_int2string.json'));
  }

  Item getItem(String id) => _string2Item[id];
}
```

You could remove the whole class and replace it with a function:

```
Future<Map<String, Item>> getItems() async => jsonDecode(
      await rootBundle.loadString('assets/data/item_int2string.json'),
    );
```

and use it like this

```
  Map<String, Item> items = await getItems();
  print(items['42']);
```

Comment: Is there a way to avoid the extra init call and do it all in the constructor? Also, is there a way to somehow declare _string2Item as a Future< Map<String, Item> > so I can check for completion elsewhere?

Comment: Constructors (even factory constructors) may not be async, so, no. Since the ItemsRepository class doesn't seem to do much any more you could replace it with a simple top level function - see updated answer.

Comment: Ok. Regarding my second question. Is it possible to declare _string2Item as a Future< Map<String, Item> > that completes once init() has finished? That way I could have multiple listeners that all await future completion and resume automatically. I'm thinking along the lines of the publish-subscribe pattern or wait()/notify() for multithreading.

Comment: You can't have multiple waiters for a Future. The Flutter alternative is a broadcast stream (as used in the BLoC pattern) or an `InheritedWidget` that delivers null (or other dummy value) until the value is available and the value after.